Is it possible to use pattern syntax for binding `self` in a method?
I can't get this to work. It seems like an arbitrary limitation that patterns can be used in function arguments, but not for self?
struct Foo { x: usize }

impl Foo {
    fn bar(Self {x}: Self) {}
    
    // doesn't work, syntax error
    // fn baz(self@Self {x}: Self) {}
}

fn quux(foo: Foo) {
    // doesn't work, bar is an associated function, not a method
    // foo.bar();
}

Playground

why would you want to? just use self.x within the method???
